# Android Emulator - Diagonal Lines across entire screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, artifacts

I created a 720x1280 ICS emulator using the latest Android SDK.  When the screen is displayed, there are virtual lines running diagonally from the top-left of the screen to the edges. Nothing is drawn on these lines, but the image is split and shifted on either side of them.

So if you have a line that's supposed to be horizontal and completely straight, it will have 3 sections: the first and third will be in line with each other, but the second will be shifted downward.  If you look across another horizontal line further down, you will see the same thing but the divisions are shifted to the right.

1) Has anybody else seen this?

2) Has anybody found a solution?

Comment: I can tell you I've seen it while developing the Barcode Scanner app. I have no idea why it happens. It only shows up on my tablet running 3.2.

Comment: Also seeing this on an AVD emulating 1280x720 Galaxy Nexus.  I suspect it may be an issue with the emulator when running at larger screen sizes, or possibly an emulator-specific issue to do with the new ICS screen-rotation animations.  Am hoping it wont appear on an actual device...